# my pygame sprite wont move

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

im trying to get a sprite to move around the screen with a walk animation and all it will do is stay stationary but it still goes through the animation.
here's the code:

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame._view

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

height = 500
width = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('placeholder text')

photo = 'grassbackground.png'
background = pygame.image.load(photo).convert()

photo1 = 1

user = pygame.sprite.Sprite()

change = False

x, y = (0, 0)

up = False
down = False
left = False
right = False

speed = 3

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = True
                y += 1
                change = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
                y -= 1
                change = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
                x -= 1
                change = True
            if event.type == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
                x += 1
                change = True

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = False
                change = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
                change = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False
                change = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
                change = False

if down and user.rect.bottom < height:
    user.rect.top += speed
if up and user.rect.top > 0:
    user.rect.top -= speed
if left and user.rect.left > 0:
    user.rect.left -= speed
if right and user.rect.right < width:
    user.rect.right += speed

if change == True:
    pygame.time.wait(110)
    photo1 += 1

if change == False:
    photo1 = 1

if photo1 == 1:
    user.image = pygame.image.load("1.png").convert()
    user.rect = user.image.get_rect()
    screen.blit(user.image, user.rect)

if photo1 == 2:
    user.image = pygame.image.load("2.png").convert()
    user.rect = user.image.get_rect()
    screen.blit(user.image, user.rect)

if photo1 == 3:
    user.image = pygame.image.load("3.png").convert()
    user.rect = user.image.get_rect()
    screen.blit(user.image, user.rect)

if photo1 >= 4:
    photo1 = 1

thesprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((user))
thesprites.update()

screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
thesprites.draw(screen)

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```

(p.s. im not sure why i have the x and y coordinates in there, i guess i just put that there in case i decided to use it)
im not using any defined class and would prefer not to. thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell for sure, because you haven't included the image files necessary to run your app.

I can't comment on posts because I haven't been active enough, but it looks like you're recreating the rect here:

```
if photo1 == 1:
    user.image = pygame.image.load("1.png").convert()
    user.rect = user.image.get_rect()
    screen.blit(user.image, user.rect)

if photo1 == 2:
    user.image = pygame.image.load("2.png").convert()
    user.rect = user.image.get_rect()
    screen.blit(user.image, user.rect)

if photo1 == 3:
    user.image = pygame.image.load("3.png").convert()
    user.rect = user.image.get_rect()
    screen.blit(user.image, user.rect)
```

even though you adjust it a few lines above:

```
if down and user.rect.bottom < height:
    user.rect.top += speed
if up and user.rect.top > 0:
    user.rect.top -= speed
if left and user.rect.left > 0:
    user.rect.left -= speed
if right and user.rect.right < width:
    user.rect.right += speed
```

You have to store the rect that is used for the player's position, and then re-apply it to the rect after you create the new image.

Beyond that, look into creating and using functions, the code here could benefit greatly from having them. Take a look here for more information on that:  http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/functions/